# Use 1 unique MFC dialog for multiple different objects of the same class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am more use to Qt than MFC, but I have the following concern:

I was creating a panel with 4 buttons, all these buttons have the same purpose, if you click on them it opens another dialog.

This dialog has the exact same layout for the 4 buttons.

However since a dialog is associated to a class via the enum { IDD = ...} I was wondering if it was actually possible to use the same template of dialog for more than one object or if I had to actually create 4 dialogs doing basically the same thing with a different id??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource ID in the statement `enum { IDD = <resource ID> };` defines a compile-time constant, that is passed to the `CDialog`-c'tor (by default<sup>1)</sup>) to construct the native controls from a dialog template resource. This is then passed to one of the dialog creation functions ([CreateDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434.aspx), etc.) to do the heavy lifting.

There are no restrictions to prevent using a single dialog template for multiple `CDialog`-derived classes.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *You can pass the dialog template resource ID directly to the `CDialog`-c'tor in your custom class implementation, and do not need to use the standard enumerated value `IDD`.*

Comment: I did not treat it a resource and your explanation made things clearer

Comment: @Ajay: The `enum` is just your average enumerated value (I have no clue, what you mean by *"not first class C++"*; there's nothing particularly spectacular about it). If multiple classes define a member with the same name, then this is not a violation of the single definition rule. The members are scoped to their enclosing class. In other words: Every `CDialog`-derived class can have a class member named `IDD` (and it did so for decades). Irrespective of that, any number of dialog implementation can use the same dialog template resource.